# Setting layout dynamically

Tags: android

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
```

How do I write the above XML in code?

```
android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);
```

Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Create the layout params
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

//Create the LinearLayout
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(context);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL); //set orientation
ll.setLayoutParams(params); //asign your layout params
```